# Hide one button and show another one after ajax completes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a form for registration, that is a two step process. For that reason, I have two buttons:

```
<button style="display: block" type="submit" name="check" id="check" class="btn btn-primary btn-block"><?php esc_html_e('Check', 'theme'); ?></button>
<button style="display: none;" type="submit" name="book" id="book" class="btn btn-primary btn-block"><?php esc_html_e('Book', 'theme'); ?></button>
```

My idea is you check something when pressing the first button, that calls on my JavaScript code, that runs an AJAX request. At the end of the request, I want to hide the first button, and show the second one, that is used to submit the whole form (first button checks dates, and then shows more fields). 
However, this does not work. Here is my JavaScript code:

```
$("#reservationform").submit(function(e) {
        var url = document.getElementById('reservationform').action,
            fromDate = document.getElementById('checkin').value,
            toDate = document.getElementById('checkout').value,// the script where you handle the form input.
            dataString = 'fromDate=' + fromDate + '&toDate=' + toDate;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: dataString,
            success: function(name)
            {
                document.getElementById('rooms').innerHTML = name;
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault(); // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
        $("button#check").css("display", "none");
        $("button#book").css("display", "block");
    });
```

Code works up until the last 3 lines, as the default event is blocked, my code is submitted and I get the requested data back as specified in a div with id="rooms". What am I doing wrong, because the buttons are not being hidden/shown?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$("#reservationform").submit(function(e) {
    var url = document.getElementById('reservationform').action,
        fromDate = document.getElementById('checkin').value,
        toDate = document.getElementById('checkout').value,// the script where you handle the form input.
        dataString = 'fromDate=' + fromDate + '&toDate=' + toDate;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: dataString,
        success: function(name)
        {
            document.getElementById('rooms').innerHTML = name;
        },
        complete: function() {
          // write it here

          $("button#check").css("display", "none");
          $("button#book").css("display", "block");
        }
    });

    e.preventDefault(); // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.

});
```

Comment: what about $("button#check").hide(); and $("button#book").show(); ?

Comment: I had an error elsewhere, after fixing it, this works, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Create one class for hidden

```
.hidden{
display :none;
}
```

And your initial HTML would be

```
<button type="submit" name="check" id="check" class="btn btn-primary btn-block"><?php esc_html_e('Check', 'theme'); ?></button>

<button type="submit" name="book" id="book" class="btn btn-primary btn-block hidden"><?php esc_html_e('Book', 'theme'); ?></button>
```

And ajax

```
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: dataString,
            success: function(name)
            {
                document.getElementById('rooms').innerHTML = name;
                $("#check").addClass("hidden");
                $("#book").removeClass("hidden");
            }
});

e.preventDefault();
```

Comment: You've forgotten a " in the addClass, but even with that corrected, it's not doing the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Write `e.preventDefault();` after display/hide button script execution:

```
$("#reservationform").submit(function(e) {
        var url = document.getElementById('reservationform').action,
            fromDate = document.getElementById('checkin').value,
            toDate = document.getElementById('checkout').value,// the script where you handle the form input.
            dataString = 'fromDate=' + fromDate + '&toDate=' + toDate;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: dataString,
            success: function(name)
            {
                document.getElementById('rooms').innerHTML = name;
                // write it here

                 $("button#check").css("display", "none");
                 $("button#book").css("display", "block");
            }
        });



        e.preventDefault(); // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.

    });
```

Comment: I've tried moving the button changing jquery everywhere, the result is the same. Even at the top, before the var declarations, they don't work.

Comment: try to put it in success

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("#reservationform button[type=submit]").on('click', function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    ... 
    })
```

or some kind of targeting the "submit" buttons for "click" event as you cant prevent the submit event AFTER it has fired :)

Comment: Doesn't work. Also, my text editor spilled a bunch of warnings about inefficient jquery code

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
$(document).on('sublit', '#reservationform',function(e) {
    var url = document.getElementById('reservationform').action,
        fromDate = document.getElementById('checkin').value,
        toDate = document.getElementById('checkout').value,// the script where you handle the form input.
        dataString = 'fromDate=' + fromDate + '&toDate=' + toDate;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: dataString,
        success: function(name)
        {
            document.getElementById('rooms').innerHTML = name;
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault(); // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
    $("button#check").hide();
    $("button#book").show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#reservationform").submit(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
        var url = document.getElementById('reservationform').action,
            fromDate = document.getElementById('checkin').value,
            toDate = document.getElementById('checkout').value,// the script where you handle the form input.
            dataString = 'fromDate=' + fromDate + '&toDate=' + toDate;
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: url,
            data: dataString,
            success: function(name)
            {
                document.getElementById('rooms').innerHTML = name;
            }, 
            complete: function() {
               $("button#check").css("display", "none");
              $("button#book").css("display", "block");
            }
        });
         // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.

    });
```

check on [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/ychlkVvzObh9Cdj8yx4c?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

i think that dont need css or class
easy so

```
$('#form-btn-delete').show();
$('#form-btn-save').hide();
```

that have the same effect in HTML

```
style="display: none;
```

Comment: Hi Rtronic, that's inline CSS, not HTML.